# Hibernate @OneToMany / @ManyToOne column not appearing

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have a `@OneToMany` / `@ManyToOne` relationship, where a `Project` can have one or many `Phases` and a `Phase` depends on a `Project`. Pretty simple.

Here are my entities (the relevant parts):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
public class ProjectEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "project_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    // Our Set of phases to be saved in the database as an array 
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = PhaseEntity.class)
    private Set<PhaseEntity> phases = new HashSet<>(0);

    // Getters and setters
}
```

And my `PhaseEntity`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "phase")
public class PhaseEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, name="phase_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    // Our project on which the phases are appart of   
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = ProjectEntity.class)
    private ProjectEntity project;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Upon creating phases in an already existing project, I save them one by one by creating an entity and

```
phaseDao.save(phaseEntity);
```

And finally save the set of phases in my project like such:

```
project.setPhases(phaseSet);
```

My phases ARE correctly created and are linked to a project but my projects do not show any sign of phases as they do not have a `phases` column.

**EDIT: Turns out that Hibernate creates a link table called `project_phases`, is there a way to save an array of phases without creating a link table?**

What am I not understanding?

Comment: Looks like you forget the `mappedBy = "project"` and perhaps `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use mappedBy attribute in @OneToMany Annotation

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = PhaseEntity.class, mappedby="project")
private Set<PhaseEntity> phases = new HashSet<>(0);
```

Comment: use @joinColumn annotation in PhaseEntity.

`@ManyToOne(targetEntity = ProjectEntity.class)
@JoinColumn(name="project_id")
    private ProjectEntity project;`

Comment: Thank you, I guess I had a wrong understanding or vision of my DB relationship. I can access the phases in a project by querying my phases table by my project's ID.